# Spring Cloud Gateway on Heroku

Tags: heroku, spring-cloud-gateway

The setup, Heroku hosted (private space):

1. Spring Boot Eureka Registry
2. Spring Boot Cloud Gateway
3. Node.JS microservice

The issue:
The first few requests hit the gateway and route to the micro-service, and respond successfully all the way to the client.

After around 30 seconds, the gateway begins to throw the following error:
The connection observed an error
reactor.netty.http.client.PrematureCloseException: Connection has been closed BEFORE response, while sending request body
as well as
reactor.netty.channel.AbortedException: Connection has been closed

We've played around with the configurations for the http client pool settings, including:

a) reducing the maxLifetime, maxIdleTime, to a minimum, so that each new request spins up a new connection, and setting the leasingStrategy to lifo.

b) disabling pool altogether

Configurations:

(a) application.java

```
ConnectionProvider provider = ConnectionProvider.builder("custom")
            .maxConnections(1500)
            .maxIdleTime(Duration.ofMillis(500))
            .maxLifeTime(Duration.ofMillis(1))
            .pendingAcquireTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(-1))
            .evictInBackground(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
            .lifo()
            .build();
```

(b) application.yml

```
reactor.netty.pool:
  maxConnections: 400
  maxIdleTime: 2000
  maxLifeTime: 15000
  responseTimeout: 7000
  acquireTimeout: 8000
  disposeInactivePoolsInBackground: true
  disposeTimeout: 5000
  evictInBackground: true
  leasingStrategy: lifo

spring:
  application:
    name: routing-service
  cloud:
    loadbalancer.ribbon.enabled: false
    gateway:
      httpclient:
        pool:
          type: fixed
          maxConnections: 400
          maxIdleTime: 8000
          maxLifeTime: 15000
          responseTimeout: 7000
          acquireTimeout: 8000
          disposeInactivePoolsInBackground: true
          disposeTimeout: 5000
          evictInBackground: true
          leasingStrategy: lifo
        wiretap: true
```

In the case of configuration (a): We expected that the lifecycle of the connection pool, set to well below Heroku's 30 second request limit, would not be killed by heroku. We observed similar symptoms to the above.
Response time was surprisingly below 3.5 seconds somehow.

In the case of configuration (b): We expected that having no connection pools, a request would be created and destroyed as soon as it was complete. In this case, our gateway saw response times > 30 seconds.

Comment: I suggest you contact Heroku support about this

Comment: @Chris  from your experience, any inkling as to what this might be?